# How can we Delete multiple Id's from database using Stored procedure at single instance?

Tags: .net, api, sql-server-2008, .net-core

This is my stored Procedure

```sql
IF(@mode='DELETE')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ProjectCostingTypes SET [IsDeleted] = 1, [ModifiedBy] = 1, [ModifiedOn] = GETDATE() 
            WHERE [ProjectCostingTypeId] =@Id 
            SELECT IsDeleted,ProjectCostingTypeId
            FROM ProjectCostingTypes WHERE ProjectCostingTypeId=@Id
        END
```

below this is my repository

```cs
public async Task<string> DeleteMultipleProjectCostingTypeByID(List<int> Ids)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
                {
                    foreach (int id in Ids)
                    {
                        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                        parameters.Add(APIConstants.PARAM_NAME_ID, id);
                        parameters.Add(APIConstants.PARAM_NAME_MODE, APIConstants.PARAM_VALUE_DELETE);
                        parameters.Add(APIConstants.PARAM_NAME_MASTER, APIConstants.PROJECT_COSTING_TYPE);

                        var data = await connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<ProjectCostingTypes>(APIConstants.DELETE_PROJECT_COSTING_TYPES, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                        // var data = await connection.QueryAsync(APIConstants.DELETE_PROJECT_COSTING_TYPES, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    }
                    return "Deleted data successfully";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is by adjusting the stored procedure in the following way:

Declare the Id as varchar

```
@Id varchar(4096)
```

Adjusting the select statement like:

```
SELECT IsDeleted,ProjectCostingTypeId FROM ProjectCostingTypes WHERE ProjectCostingTypeId in (' + @Id + ')'
```

When you call the stored procedure pass the Id(s) as comma separated string like

```
'5,28'
```

Comment: can u please send the implement the logic and send it